# Append data in teradata table from Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, teradata

Is it possible to use teradata hadoop connector to append values into an existing tables in teradata? please help!

Comment: Yes, sqoop can insert new rows.

Comment: thanks andrew. I have a required to use teradata connector and not sqoop for export. Is it possible to append data using teradata-hadoop connector jar?